# How to redirect traffic for an AWS load balancer using the aws-cli command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

Right now I need to login to the web console, click load balancer -> LB instance name -> listener -> rules, then "forward to" the intended server.

This is a lot of manual clicks. Is there an equivalent using the `aws` command?

I find the official documentation hard to navigate. Is there a better online resource in general?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/

Comment: You will probably be happier using a tool like Terraform, rather than attempting to patch your LB configurations using the command-line. It's all there with the CLI, but it's a thin wrapper around the actual web-service calls. Versus maintaining a holistic, declarative view of your resource with Terraform (or CloudFormation, but TF lets you import existing resources and CF doesn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLI command that you are looking for is `aws elbv2 create-rule`, or if you want to modify already existing rules then `aws elbv2 modify-rule`.

[aws elbv2 create-rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/create-rule.html)

[aws elbv2 modify-rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/modify-rule.html)